# From Service Cloud Console sidebar, unable to open record page from lookup field

Tags: service-cloud-console, fieldsets

**Issue :**
I'm displaying a **fieldset**  in the visualforce page(Detail Page) as custom console component .The fieldset contains text, Number and lookup fields.
So, I'm using the component to display the values from different data types. The issue is, when we click on **lookup field link** it's not opening any record in console.(Its working fine in non console/classic mode). I've verified with different solutions for this issue but still i am facing issue.

Can you please share any solution or ideas on this.

I've researched for this and found similar questions, but not specifically for a lookup field with Field Set on Console.

Output Field Generated Url :

```
javascript:srcUp(%27https%3A%2F%2Fcs21.salesforce.com%2F001q000000UCjKn%3Fisdtp%3Dvw%27);
```

**Expected Format** :  `javascript:srcUp(%27 %2F001q000000UCjKn%3Fisdtp%3Dvw%27);`

[image: VF Page Screenshot - Fieldset - Output Field]

**VF Code :**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Site Information" collapsible="false">
      <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Site__c.fieldsets.SiteDeatilsFS}" var="fieldValue">
           <apex:outputfield value="{!con[fieldValue]}" />
      </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```